# Work benefits in France

Tags: france, job-hunting

I got an offer as a data scientist in France. I am a bit puzzled by the fact that it includes only the raw salary. There are no signing bonuses, production bonuses or similar. Is it normal in France or is it something that I might be able to negotiate?

Comment: It will depend on the company hiring you. But : _signing bonuses_ are really not common in France. _production bonuses_ (if I understand what it is) are more common (but not mandatory). They might be called _part variable_, _prime sur objectifs_, _prime de fin d'année_.

Comment: I wonder if that question wouldn't be more fitted for https://workplace.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: Thank you for the info! How much do you think that, in general, it is possible to negotiate the base salary offer? Can I expect to pull off (if well motivated of course) a 10% increase?

Comment: I have launched a request for your question to be migrated to https://workplace.stackexchange.com/ where you hopefully will get more attention. See https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic _Finding employment (resumes/cv/cover letters, recruiters, hiring-managers, interviews, negotiations, etc.)_